# iOS Local notifications - sound not playing

Tags: ios, swift, audio

My local notifications are working, and the alert is showing, however the sound is not playing. I am testing on a device as I know it won't play in the simulator.

```
let notificationAlert = UILocalNotification()
```

class DailyAlarmViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!


@IBAction func alarmSetButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    notificationAlert.fireDate = timePicker.date
    notificationAlert.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notificationAlert.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
    notificationAlert.alertAction = "Open Survive to Thrive Nation!"
    notificationAlert.alertBody = "Time to wake up and complete your Journal!"
    notificationAlert.soundName = "Alarm_Clock.wav"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notificationAlert)     

}

@IBAction func cancelAlarm(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notificationAlert)      
}
```

Do I need to add Background Mode or Inter App Audio? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added bundled your sound file with project resources? It won't play the sound if your app can't find the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try instead of `Alarm_Clock.wav` to use the default alarm sound `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`. If it works, then may be the problem is with the `Alarm_Clock.wav`.

Answer (score 0):

You must check the .wav file had add to the reaource of the app.